# Application icon for each activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have used web view in two of my layouts in the application and when I install the application in my phone I could see separate icons for the activities whose layouts have web view.  How will i fix this issue and why does this happen so? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason is that you have several activities in manifest that have the MAIN, launcher intent. To fix it, remove it from one of them.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

to

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```