# Publishing Xamarin Android apk

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am learning currently Xamarin, I have built a simple app, set it up as release and then publish it. Everything is fine, I get an APK file, but when I send that APK to my phone, and install it, it gives me 2 parts of my application.
I have 2 activities, and each of those activities has its own layout(axml), I thought when I publish my app, it installs and I have only one application, and then navigate in it to other parts. If I have 5 activities, I will get 5 parts of that on my phone(5 icons next to each other, all named after some activity).
What I might be doing wrong? I dont get any build warnings nor errors.

Comment: It sounds like you're making every activity launchable in the manifest. Can you share your manifest file? I think each activity has `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one Activity should be flagged as `MainLauncher = true`:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/application_name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
```

Any other Activities should be flagged as `MainLauncher = false`, the default is `false` so you can just remove it:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/application_name")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question was given in post - [Application icon for each activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733870/application-icon-for-each-activity?answertab=active#tab-top).

> Probably the reason is that you have several activities in manifest that have the MAIN, launcher intent. To fix it, remove it from one of them.